# swiping right in ios is like swiping left

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I use the following code to swipe right/left in ios simulator

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myLeftAction)];
[leftRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer: leftRecognizer];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer * rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myRightAction)];
[rightRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer: rightRecognizer];
```

This code is in viewDidLoad()

unfortunately, swiping right or left doesn't work. I have to swipe left to be able to get the swipe right effect. and I have to swipe right to be able to get the swipe left effect.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're code seems to be ok.

This looks like a matter of meaning when it comes to swipe direction. For iOS left swipe means a swipe where the swipe movement continues to left from the starting point. And vice versa for the right swipes.